# java radio buttons in jface automatically setting the first button to true

Tags: java, radio-button, swt, jface, radiobuttonlist

Here is a puzzler, every time I create a group of radio buttons in SWT/JFace, the first button is always true, but if create a standard button and call it to reset the radio button it will reset to being false.
I would like it to be set to false as default.
Has any encountered a problem like this and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a group of radio buttons, exactly one from them HAS to be selected at a time. By selecting a different button, the first one becomes unselected. Therefor, if you set selected true to second radio button, the first will be unselected.

If you create a group of radio buttons, the first one is always selected by default. Use

```
secondRadioButton.setSelection(true);
```

to change the state...

Comment: You might want to change the method name to `setSelection(boolean)`, since `setSelected(boolean)` does not exist.